# Azure php web app web.config not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, azure, iis, azure-web-app-service

I have following rule for showing **avatar.jpg** (`/images/avatar.jpg`) for not found jpg. I have converted  `.htaccess` to `web.config` using **IIS manager**.

Here is the .htaccess rule which is working file in regular apache server,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(jpg)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .*$ /images/user-default.png [L]
```

Here is the converted web.config file (`/uploads/web.config`),

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 3" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="\.(jpg)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/images/avatar.png" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

which still gives 404 not found error for non existing images.

Answer (score 0):

By default, static files such as images on Azure in PHP application do not require additionally configuration to show up on browsers. You can try with a new empty PHP Azure Web App only including `images` folder with test image files.
[image]
It should works fine as except.

Regarding to your issue, it should due to the route configuration in your PHP application. It requests for static files may be intercepted and try to match the route in the PHP application, which raises the `NOT FOUND` issue.

You can try remove the `web.config` files for further troubleshooting.